# Android TextToSpeech, set Gender?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

When using Android TextToSpeech , is there any way I can specify the Gender of the voice, for example `tts.setGender(TextToSpeech.MALE)`  or  `tts.speak("<voice gender='male'>Hello </voice>")` ?

Thank you for your time,

Best regards,

James

Answer (score 2):

The voice data (used to generate speech) is very specific to a specific voice, and data size is huge - mobile device wise. So you cannot randomly switch male/female.  Take [Ivona voices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts&hl=en)  for example, you can download voice data for US English (Kendra, female) or UK English (Amy, Female), each has data size of ~150 MB.

You can try to play different languages (US vs. UK), depending on user's voice data loaded, it may be male, may be female.

As for pitch and speed, yes, you can change TTS pitch and speed. Though I tried, it did not sound well, but it might depend on which voice data you are using.

The APIs:

```
tts.setPitch(float pitch);
tts.setSpeechRate(float speechRate);
```

In both cases, parameter 1.0 means 'normal' pitch/rate.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `tts.setLanguage` to `Locale.UK` for female and `Locale.US` for male

```
if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
```

Or

```
if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

The only caveat is that this only works with newer Android versions, I think 4.0 and above. This blog [post](http://fatdevz.blogspot.com/2013/02/text-to-speech-gender.html) has more information about it.

Comment: That is a good idea for English, but unfortunately I need to use a German voice, which is female using DefaultEngine.  I will try to download another Engine (with male voice), and see if I can switch between voices.
Das ist eine gute Idee für Englisch, aber leider muss ich eine deutsche Stimme benutzen, die weiblich ist mit DefaultEngine.  Ich werde versuchen, ein anderes Engine herunterladen (mit männlicher Stimme), und sehe, ob ich zwischen Stimmen umschalten kann.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same, but after doing some research, there is no way to configure the voice. Neither pitch, speed nor gender